# select user name and surname from user table using array values

Tags: php

I have this code in php:

```
<?php

$arstring = implode(' ',$array);

?>
```

the $arstring while output some values like 23, 30 etc. I have a table users(user_id, name, surname). My question is how can I get all names and surnames from users table, that have a user_id equal to those that outputs $arstring. For example how to get all names surnames from users that have user_id equal to 23, 30 etc..

Answer (score 0):

The query would be something like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE
    user_id IN (' . implode(', ', $array) . ')';
```

PS: if $array contains data that comes directly from the user as input and you haven't sanitized it, before running the query you should make sure that $array contains only integers (so to avoid SQL injections). You may use this code (*before* the query):

```
$array = array_map('intval', $array);
```